# Heroku Deploy - “Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app”

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, heroku

Trying to deploy a Laravel+vue application to heroku but when using git push heroku master I get the following trace (only part of the whole trace is shown but it is the part which I believe to be the problem - if not let me know):

```
remote:        npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
remote:        npm ERR! sha512- 
Prh/h9CB1jBCBIjSLD6kvIWhMV5S25Bwv7yK0fYJSOTIyg1CmU9OqNdRVCkdWyQY1Hkvm+1YdXJzh3xYupq1KA== 
integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512- 
Prh/h9CB1jBCBIjSLD6kvIWhMV5S25Bwv7yK0fYJSOTIyg1CmU9OqNdRVCkdWyQY1Hkvm+1YdXJzh3xYupq1KA== but 
got sha512- 
QItiGZBy5TstGy+q8mjQTMGRlDDOARXLxH+sgVm1n/LYeo0zFcQlcCh8m4zi8QxctrxB9Kue/lStc/RD5iLadQ==. 
(896052 bytes)
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.8lpmC/_logs/2020-06-05T11_28_24_085Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js- 
version
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
```

and this my package.json

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"dev": "npm run development",
"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
"watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
"hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"prod": "npm run production",
"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"postinstall": "npm run prod",
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run prod"
},
"devDependencies": {
"axios": "^0.19",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
"cross-env": "^5.1",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.13",
"popper.js": "^1.12",
"resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
"sass": "^1.20.1",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
"vue": "^2.5.17",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
},
"dependencies": {
"@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.0",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.4.0",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.4.0",
"@fullcalendar/vue": "^4.4.0",
"@types/dhtmlxgantt": "^6.0.2",
"admin-lte": "^3.0.2",
"babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.15.0",
"dhtmlx-gantt": "^6.3.7",
"laravel-echo": "^1.7.0",
"laravel-vue-pagination": "^2.3.1",
"mdbvue": "^6.7.0",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"pusher-js": "^5.1.1",
"sweetalert2": "^9.8.2",
"vform": "^1.0.1",
"vue-full-calendar": "^2.7.0",
"vue-print-nb": "^1.5.0",
"vue-progressbar": "^0.7.5",
"vue-router": "^3.1.6",
"vuex": "^3.1.3"
},
"engines": {
"node": "12.x"
}
}
```

There's a bunch of error inside and I have no idea why this happen. but after many research  i  try many ways bu i didn't find the solution .So any help guys i'm stuck here since 2 days

Comment: Try specifying an npm version as well: `"npm": "6.x"`


https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-an-npm-version

Comment: Look into your `package-lock.json` file ctrl+f for `sha512- 
QItiGZBy5TstGy+q8mjQTMGRlDDOARXLxH+sgVm1n/LYeo0zFcQlcCh8m4zi8QxctrxB9Kue/lStc/RD5iLadQ==` deinstall the mentioned package and install again. Commit and push to Heroku again.

Comment: I try it but the same result @GeonGeorge

Comment: The integrity check error is definitely from the `package-lock.json`. What happens if you remove the `package-lock.json` and then deploy the app - do you still get the error? Also, what happens when you run `npm ci` locally with the `package-lock.json` in place? Do you get the same error?

Comment: when i remove the package-lock.json i got this error
 > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_169da5ac7ea03d1575b1f90a1c13d36f/node_modules/fsevents
remote:        > node install.js
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported
remote:        npm ERR! Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
@DanielleAdams

Answer (score 1):

Where you have specified the node version also specify the node version.
see if it works. It worked for me.

`"engines": { "node": "12.x", "npm": "your version" }`

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the `engines` object-block helped me with both a Laravel app and a Rails app

**package.json (append)**

```
"engines": {
    "node": "12.x"
}
```

Sort-of odd, but when it works, it works.

I also added a @dependabot rebase so that my preview builds using heroku would allow me to verify in-branch that this was the only problem preventing the applications from building.

Answer (score 0):

Check your versions of node and npm in terminal:

```
node -v

npm -v
```

and update both in your package.json (example):

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x",
    "npm": "7.x"
  }
```

just putting node version didn't help me since heroku automatically tried to build another version of npm and crashed

read more here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specify-the-version-of-node